# How to assign distinct cell values for every record based on some conditions in a table?

Tags: sas, coding-efficiency

I have to assign distinct cell values for every record given some conditions in a table.

[image: Table]

In the image, `column1= elig, column2=status, column3= type, column4 =metro, column5=quartile, column6=urb, column7=cell`. The first 3 conditions I just wrote in an if then else (they are from another table).

But once I start using the variable `quartile, urb and type I need a better code than what I wrote.

- Metro will increments from 1-4.
- Quartile increments with every other record.
- Type changes as a group.

For the first block `type = 1`, for the second block `type maybe be 4 or 5` (not necessarily incremental). The next type group may be `type 7,8,9,10`.

Only the cell value changes for every record. I know I can substitute macro vars to shorten names and save typing but how can I make this code compact and more efficient.

Many thanks in advance.

```
 If elig=0 then cell=0;

 else if elig =1 then 
do;
   if status in ('2','3') then cell=1;
   else if ( status = ' ' and typec=25 )  then cell =2;
    else if (status ='1','4','') and (quartile = . )  then cell=2;
end;

     else if  elig= '1' and type =1 and metro eq='1' then 
do;
       if quartile = 1 and urb in ('1','2') then cell =1111;
else if quartile = 1 and urb = '3'  then cell =1112; 
else if quartile = 2 and urb in ('1','2') then cell =1121;
else if quartile = 2 and urb = '3'  then cell =1122; 
else if quartile =3 and urb in ('1','2') then cell =1141;
else if quartile = 3 and urb = '3'  then cell =1142; 
else if quartile = 4 and urb in ('1','2') then cell =1121;
else if quartile = 4 and urb = '3'  then cell =1172; 
end;
/*here will be 3 more blocks of code for metro =2,3,4* /
/*note type changes value after metro cycles through 4 iterations*/

    else if elig='1' and  type =('4','5') and metro eq='1 then 
do;
if quartile = 1 and urb in ('1','2') then cell =1211;
else if quartile = 1 and urb = '3'  then cell =1212; 
else if quartile = 2 and urb in ('1','2') then cell =1221;
else if quartile = 2 and urb = '3'  then cell =1222; 
else  if quartile =3 and urb in ('1','2') then cell =1241;
else if quartile = 3 and urb = '3'  then cell =1242; 
else if quartile = 4 and urb in ('1','2') then cell =1271;
else if quartile = 4 and urb = '3'  then cell =1272; 
end;
/*3 more blocks of code for metro =2,3,4* /
/*then type changes and metro=1 and so on*/
else if elig='1' and type  type =('7','8') and metro eq=1 then 
    do;  
/*more code until my groups end* /
   end;
```

Comment: Can you post some sample input and output data?

Comment: I added an image of the first table where type =1, note that type changes, its grouped like this. Type =1, type=(4,5,6), Type=(7,8,9,10,11)

Comment: I'm sure as hell not typing out your data...I would suggest creating that table and then doing a lookup via a merge instead of IF/THEN statements. I'd also bet there's a mathematical logic to the formula's being assigned that could help determine the code, but I'm not quite seeing it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the data you have posted, you just need to recode your original variables and concatenate the results.

e.g.

```
data out_data;
    set in_data;
length class_12 $2 class_3 class_4 $1 class $4.;

select (type);
    when (1) 
     do;
        select (metro);
            when (1) class_12 = '11';
            when (2) class_12 = '12';
            when (3) class_12 = '14';
            otherwise;
        end;
     end;
    when (4, 5) 
      do;
        select (metro);
            when (1) class_12 = '21';
            when (2) class_12 = '22';
            when (3) class_12 = '24';
            otherwise;
        end;
    end;
    otherwise;
end;
select (quartile);
    when (1) class_3 = '1';
    when (2) class_3 = '2';
    when (3) class_3 = '4';
    when (4) class_3 = '7';
    otherwise;
end;
select (urb);
    when (1, 2) class_4 = '1';
    when (3) class_4 = '2';
    otherwise;
end;
class = class_12||class_3||class_4;
run;
```

Add your additional conditions and if needed introduce further variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will try it and let you know.